# appengine endpoints POST method throwing 414 "Request-URI Too Large" when parameter value is long

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

When the values in keywords parameter are too long, it throws

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 414 Request-URI Too Large

Though HttpMethod is POST, it is still trying to send the values in the URL.
Following is the ApiMethod declaration.

```
@ApiMethod(name="savePersonAsAdmin")
public Person savePersonAsAdmin(@Named("name") String name, @Nullable @Named("keywords") String keywordCsv)
```

Also tried setting httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST explicitly, but still the same error.

Comment: Could you let us know on what is too long ? At what point is the error happening and does it go away if you reduce it to a smaller size ?

Comment: we see the error only when keywords parameter value is very long. last I tested was with 500 chars.

Comment: If you test your application locally in API Explorer, do you see a GET instead of POST for this method invocation ?

Comment: Yes I see it all appended in URL